# windows batch script - setting variable inside for loop

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

maybe i'm not representing my question clear, here's the actual code i did:

```
@echo off

set /p keywords="Enter keywords to search: " %=%

dir /b *.dat > filelist.txt

for /f "delims=." %%f in (filelist.txt) do (
   for /f "delims= " %%g in (%%f.dat) do (
      7z e %%g *sec.evtx
      dir /b *.evtx > evtfile.txt
      set /p tmpvar1=<evtfile.txt
      del *.evtx
   )
)
```

### filelist.txt

```
tsnint1.dat
webint1.dat
```

### tsnint1.dat

```
TSNINT1-201312091700.zip
TSNINT1-201312091600.zip
TSNINT1-201312091500.zip
TSNINT1-201312091400.zip
TSNINT1-201312091300.zip
TSNINT1-201312091200.zip
```

### webint1.dat

```
WEBINT1-201312091300.zip
WEBINT1-201312091200.zip
```

the problem i'm facing is, evtfile consists of the right content but tmpvar1 is not assigned correctly as expected, what is my mistake and how to correct it? many thanks

Comment: put the line `set tmpvar1` before `del *.evtx` and tell us the output

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, however, adding this line doesn't affecting the output

Comment: 2 lines should be the same as expected, however, current output is:WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
TSNINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
TSNINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
TSNINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
TSNINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
TSNINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
TSNINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx
WEBINT1-20131209-sec.evtx

Comment: no, it does not affect output - but it can give us a hint, what is going wrong. So what does it say=

Comment: output remains unchanged after adding that line

Comment: I need the output of `set tmpvar1` to help you.

Comment: the set statement displays the correct output i need

Comment: That's good. That means, your tmpvar1 is set correctly. But where do you use it? Inside or outside the block? Try to understand my answer below, this should help you.

Comment: The `keywords` and `tmpvar1` variables aren't being used.  What is it you are trying to do?  Please update this in your question.

Comment: they will be processing in the remaining part of the script

Answer (score 3):

You need delayed expansion to **use** a variable inside a block when this variable has been set (or changed) inside the same block. But you can **set** a variable without delayed expansion.

See this little demonstration (I used a simple `if` construct instead of `for`, but the effect is the same (not with `if` or `for`, but with *blocks* (inside `(` and `)`).

```
@echo off
REM SETTING a variable inside a block
set "var=ONE"
echo start: %var%
if 1==1 (
  echo   inside block: %var%
  set var=TWO
  echo   var has a new value:
  set var
  echo   inside block is still old: %var%
)
echo after block: %var%

echo ----------

REM USING a variable inside a block
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=ONE"
echo start: %var%
if 1==1 (
  echo   inside block: %var%
  set var=TWO
  echo   var has a new value:
  set var
  echo   new value inside block: !var!
  echo   just to demonstrate: %var% 
)
echo after block: %var%
endlocal
echo ----------
echo working fine: %var%
echo not available after endlocal: !var!
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, using your code as a base.  FWIW I hope that you have more than one copy of the `.evtx` files, if they are important to you.

```
@echo off
setocal enabledelayedexapnsion
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.dat') do (
   for /f "delims=" %%g in ('type "%%f" ') do (
      7z e "%%g" "*sec.evtx"
      dir /b *.evtx > evtfile.txt
      set /p tmpvar1=<evtfile.txt
      echo !tempvar!
      del *.evtx
   )
)
```

One issue is that the *.evtx files are being deleted after the first archive is created, so the subsequent ones will have nothing to archive.