# Windows batch programming - Unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am just trying out some basic batch programming. I am getting some error during execution

```
set /a x=0
:while1
if %x% leq 5 (
    echo %x%
    goto:callfun
    /dir:/Prod /user:admin /pass:anc /level:error >> C:\Logs\A.txt
   set file=C:\Logs\J_FINANCIALS_EVENING.log
   set /a "cnt=0"
   for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "!Kitchen.Error.NoRepDefinied!" /i /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
     if %cnt% NEQ 0 (
          if %x% NEQ 5 (
              DEL C:\Logs\abc.txt
              )
      set /a x=x+1
      goto :while1

)
    echo "OUTSIDE LOOP"
   echo The Status is %errorlevel%
  call:check_file
  exit /b %errorlevel%

)
  endlocal

callfun: 
CALL C:\Pentaho\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:"Admin" /job:"XXXX"
```

I am getting the error at

set /a "x = 0"

0 was unexpected at this time.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove any and all spaces on either side of `=` symbols. Your first line does not set x to 0, but sets the variable `x ` to the string ` 0` (note the spaces). Also, near the bottom you have `set /d` - there is no `/d` option. You want `/a` for math.

Comment: I edited the code above  and still getting the same error. Also code exits at if  NEQ 0 (.

Comment: You need delayed expansion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20854972/2152082 explains that.

Comment: @SomethingDark - The space issue is only valid for normal SET. It does not apply to SET /A (space before and after = is ignored)

Comment: Good to know. It's still good practice to not have any.

Answer (score 2):

Episode about 2 billion of `delayedexpansion`

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

hence - easy fix:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a x=0
:while1
if %x% leq 5 (
    echo !x!
    goto callfun

    REM this following line appear to make no sense in winbatch

    /dir:/Prod /user:admin /pass:anc /level:error >> C:\Logs\A.txt
   set "file=C:\Logs\J_FINANCIALS_EVENING.log"
   set /a cnt=0
   for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "!Kitchen.Error.NoRepDefinied!" /i /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
     if !cnt! NEQ 0 (
          if !x! NEQ 5 (
              DEL C:\Logs\abc.txt
              )
      set /a x=x+1
      goto while1

)
    echo "OUTSIDE LOOP"
   echo The Status is !errorlevel!
  call :check_file
  exit /b !errorlevel!

)
  endlocal

REM Note that this will fall-through to the process. Best add
GOTO :EOF
REM Here.

REM Colon must precede label
:callfun 
CALL C:\Pentaho\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:"Admin" /job:"XXXX" 
REM Note that this would exit the subroutine by reaching (apparent) EOF. Best add
GOTO :EOF
REM Here - as a habit - it contributes to preventing fall-through failures
REM if you add a new subroutine and forget to include the newly-required goto :eof
```

Notes:

GOTO does **not** require a colon on the label **except** in the special case of `:EOF` which is defined to mean `end of file`

SET /a does **not** need quotes.

SET "stringname=stringvalue" is good syntax for string-assignments because the quotes cause any trailing spaces on the line to **not** be included in the value assigned.

any `%var%` which is varied within the loop should become `!var!` with `delayedexpansion` to access the `run-time` rather than the `parse-time` value.

(I've only tackled the delayed-expansion errors - other problems are flagged with REMs)

Comment: But quotes are often useful with SET /A when using any of `!`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|` operators (also assignment variants). Without quotes the operators must be escaped.

Comment: @dbenham : ah, yes - true, but in nearly 20 years of writing NT-style scripts, I've never felt the urge to use those operators. Or maybe I've contrived to avoid them. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the error is caused by having a "CALL" within a parenthesis block.   Instead of using a parenthesis block inside a IF statement, put the code that is in the parenthesis in a external "GOTO method" instead.  You have to be careful with parenthesis in dos batch programming.   Personally, I have developed a code style that rarely needs them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to emphasize that anytime , in a batch file, when you have parenthesis inside parenthesis, then your getting yourself into trouble.  Try re-writing the script without using any parenthesis and I bet it works.  You should ONLY use parenthesis when you are sure that what you are doing isn't going to be problematic to the DOS parser.